# Unable to make a portable Fortran executable in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, fortran, static-libraries

I'm attempting to compile a relatively simple Fortran executable so that it can be passed around to other Windows users that don't have Cygwin (or something of the sort) installed, however, I'm unable to get the executable to operate as a standalone.  I've tried `gfortran -static file.f` and `gfortran -static-libgfortran file.f`, however other users always encounter this error:

> The program can’t start because cygwin1.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

From what I've read online (e.g. [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranGettingStarted)), the -static option should be sufficient.  I have verified that running the executable from my machine (DOS prompt) does work.

I have gcc (gfortran) version 4.7.3.  I should also point out this is my first attempt at compiling portable Fortran.

**Update**
After realizing that this isn't a gfortran-specific issue (thanks to replies here), searches led me to related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640115/compile-stand-alone-exe-with-cygwin) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143629/executable-file-generated-using-gcc-under-cygwin)

Comment: No, but per your comment and the first answer, I will try this out and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is partially explained in the [Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.static-linking).  The solution is to install the `mingw64-i686-gcc-fortran` package with its dependencies, and cross-compile your code with `i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran -static`.

Answer (score 1):

Just package the cygwin1.dll along with your binary file (both in the same folder) then it will run just fine.